# logistic regression does not show the correct results

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the following dataset, original version, obtained from: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/

I want to apply logistic regression to classify the samples on that dataset, my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = np.genfromtxt("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data",delimiter=",")
X = data[:,1:-1]
X[X == '?'] = '-999999'
X = X.astype(int)
y = data[:, -1].astype(int)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
lg=linear_model.LogisticRegression(n_jobs = 10)
lg.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = lg.predict(X_test)
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions)
print(cm)
score = lg.score(X_test, y_test)

print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (score.mean(), score.std() * 2))
```

I have deleted the first column because it is only the ID, and replaced the ? characters with a big number, so that it could be classified as an outlier. The problem I got is when I compare my results to the ones obtained in this page:

https://anujdutt9.github.io/ML_LogRSklearn.html

Because I am obtaining an accuracy of:

```
Accuracy: 0.34
```

and on the link mentioned before the accuracy was approximately 95%.

The results of my confusion matrix are also poor, for example, I obtain:

```
[[ 1 92]
 [ 0 47]]
```

What is wrong with my model?

Thanks

Comment: Does `linear_model.LogisticRegression` have processing for outliers? I would try imputing the mean value of the column for `?` instead.

Comment: thank you @Blorgbeard, but I typed the example that is on the webpage and it works fine, my code is the one with problems

Comment: Ok, then what does your code do differently than the example?

Comment: My code gives an awful confussion matrix, as you can see the first class is poorly compared, while the code in the web page gives good results. I have tried  converting the array to float, checking the sizes of the arrays and so on, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
X[X == '?'] = np.nan #converting ? to NaN
```

Then imputing the mean value

```
imputer = Imputer()
transformed_X = imputer.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Thanks now it works, please could you give me a more detailed answer what, theoretically, you were doing with the Imputer() function? I was wondering why in Panda that replace with 9999 worked well.

Comment: The imputer function transforms for missing values. The Imputer function takes the columns "NaN" as default missing values.  Then the Imputer function replaces the missing values with a mean value of that column.